# log4net.Config doesn't have XmlConfigurator

Tags: log4net

I have downloaded the log4net-1.2.0-beta8 and have referenced the log4net.dll. I am having issues with [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(watch=true)]. The issue is that log4net.Config doesn't have XmlConfigurator as shown in the snap shot below:

[image]

All the examples and tutorials use log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator. How do I resolve this?

Comment: log4net-1.2.0-beta8 [is 14 years old!](https://sourceforge.net/projects/log4net/files/log4net/1.2.0%20Beta8/). Get the latest version from [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi) or [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/)

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the samples of that version you should add something like:

```
// Load the configuration from the 'WebApp.dll.log4net' file
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFileExtension="log4net", Watch=true)]
```

However this version is probably the oldest version of log4net you can find on the internet. Get the latest version from nugget.